How do I convert MP4 files to AMV with FFmpeg?
Platform is macOS, and I am using Bash.
I am trying to convert all mp4 videos into AMV videos with FFmpeg.
A normal command is:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -r 10 -block_size 2205 -vf scale=w=208:h=176 output.amv

And it works.
But the video is stretched as the ratio doesn't match.
Is there any solutions?
Also I want to know if I can convert all the MP4 file into AMV file with same name.

Can't help with bash, but to set a proportional hight to the width you set you can use scale=208:-1

The height and width is limited to 208:170 in this file type.

In that case: scale=208:170:force_orignal_aspect_ratio=decrease
